# Installing SCVMM from a domain controller

Tags: domain, windows-server-2012-r2, scvmm

I'm trying to install SCVMM on a Windows Server 2012 R2, this server is not the domain controller. I have another Windows Server 2012 R2 that is the domain controller. I have read that it is not recommended to install SCVMM on a domain controller, so I am attempting to install it on the non-controller.

Info here: [Technet Blog on the subject](http://blogs.technet.com/b/scvmm/archive/2010/05/06/a-quick-q-a-on-scvmm-and-domain-controllers.aspx)

However when I try to install SCVMM I get a message saying I need to log in as a domain controller in order to install SCVMM.

So am I supposed to be installing as domain controller or not? Which server should I install VMM on? The domain controller or the non-domain controller?

Sorry if this question seems a bit vague or misplaced, but I would appreciate feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably misreading the message, which is probably telling you to log in as a *domain user* or as a *domain admin*. Make sure you are logging on to the server using a domain account (not a local account), and it has all required privileges.

Comment: How exactly do I do this? My domain account is Administrator on one server, and the other server also only has an Administrator account.

Comment: there is a domain Administrator account. That's the account you should log in with to do the install. **NOT** the local Administrator account on the server.

Comment: If you type "Administrator" as the user name, the server assumes it's the local Administrator account; you should type it using the syntax "DOMAIN\Administrator".

Comment: Oh, and *of course* I'm assuming the server is joined to the domain; if it isn't, then it definitely should be.